# modify a dataset to extend time range

Tags: sas

Sorry for the confusing title.

**Background**

data looks like this

```
Area Date Ind LB UB
A    1mar 14  1  20
A    2mar 3   1  20
B    1mar 11  7  22
B    2mar 0   7  22
```

Area has several distinct values. For each area, `LB` and `UB` are fixed across multiple dates, while `Ind` varies. `Date` always starts from month start to certain day of the month.

**Target**

My target is to run a control chart for each area to see if `Ind` exceeds the range `(LB,UB)`.

But if I just plot the raw data for each area, the `xaxis` by default not ends at the last day of the month (In the previous example, the plot will be from 1-Mar to 2-Mar instead of 31-Mar. I do know the by specifying the `xmax` option in `xaxis` the plot will extends to 31-Mar. But this only extends the `xaxis`, `LB` and `UB` still display from 1-Mar to 2-Mar, leaving the right side of the graph empty.

Thus I use `modify` to add in some date records.

**What I have done**

```
data have;
modify have;
do i = 0 to intck('day',today(),intnx('month',today(),0,'E'));
Date = today()+i;
call missing(Ind);
output;
end;
stop;
run;

proc sgplot data=have missing;
series ... Ind ...;
series ... LB ...;
series ... UB ...;
run;
```

**Question**

But this only works for one area. I need to modify each area first then plot them one by one. How can I relatively efficient to get below data

```
Area Date Ind LB UB
A    1mar 14  1  20
A    2mar 3   1  20
A    3mar .   1  20
....
A    31mar.   1  20
B    1mar 11  7  22
B    2mar 0   7  22
B    3mar .   7  22
....
B    31mar.   7  22
```

Or there's other options in `proc sgplot` to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `proc timeseries` with the by-group `area` to get it into the form that you need. The `end=` option will let you specify an ending date for your data. It looks like you're using the current month, so we'll take your `intnx` function and plop it into a set of macro functions that resolve to a date literal (most ETS procs require a date literal for some reason).

We'll use two `var` statements: one for `ind` where we fill in unobserved values with `.`, and another for `LB` & `UB` to set their unobserved values with the previous valid value.

Note that we are assuming you've already put `date` into a SAS date. Make sure you do this first before running the below code.

```
proc timeseries data=have
                out=want;
   by area;
   id Date interval=day notsorted 
           accumulate=none
           end="%sysfunc(intnx(month, %sysfunc(today() ), 0, E), date9.)"d;
   var Ind / setmissing=missing;
   var LB UB / setmissing=previous;
run;
```

Your final dataset will look exactly as you'd like.